# React Native: Possible unhandled promise rejection for firebase login

Tags: firebase, react-native, promise

I'm getting the following error: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0: Network request failed while successful login of my firebase, 
Here's the promise code, I don't see what's wrong here, any ideas?

```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => { this.setState({ error: '', loading: false }); })
            .catch(() => {
                //Login was not successful, let's create a new account
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)




                    .then((response) => { this.setState({ error: '', loading: false })


fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firebase_id: response.uid ,
    firebase_token: 'response.token',
  }),
}) .then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  return responseJson.movies;
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

; })
                        .catch(() => {
                            this.setState({ error: 'Authentication failed.', loading: false });
                        });
                });
```

Comment: you use signInWithEmailAndPassword that login into your firebase successfully
i am thinking this error occur from `https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/` 
so first check it where is error occurring 
if you face error your website and it run in nginx then ask me i will help you

Comment: Actually I have got my valid link for calling API . I don’t know why it causes unwanted promises